# Can motherboard limit maximal resolution with external graphics card?

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

My mother uses an old computer with [Intel DG45ID](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/34684/intel-desktop-board-dg45id.html) motherboard. It has an internal GMA 4500 GPU which supports up to [2048*1536](https://forums.hexus.net/graphics-cards/172370-intel-gma-4500m-list-resolutions-supported.html#post1787894) resolution (I assume the mobile GPU is no more capable than the desktop variant). I have a 2560*1440 monitor (Dell U2717D). I connected it to the computer with an hdmi cable and the maximal resolution offered is 1920*1080 (actually 1920*1200, but that is different aspect ratio). I bought ASUS 210-SL-TC1GD3-L external graphics card. It [lists](https://www.singular.com.cy/asus-210-sl-tc1gd3-l-graphics-card-gf-210-1gb-ddr3-pcie.html) 2560*1440 as its maximal resolution. However, when I installed it into the computer and connected the monitor, it still offers just the same 1920*1080 resolution. How come?

The software is Ubuntu 18.04 and I installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers, but that did not change anything.

Comment: Your ubuntu version is really old.  What kernel version are you using? uname -r  Have you been regularly updating your software?

Comment: Yeah, it is LTS, so I never bothred to update, it is my mother's computer and I think all she needs are security updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was not in the motherboard, but in the graphics card - it would only support the maximal resolution over DVI, not HDMI, so I had to get another graphics card.

Comment: I do not think your answer was correct. The first paragraph was not applicable to me. Regarding the second paragraph, I was not using a VGA cable, I was using a HDMI cable, but the HDMI did not provide the full resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you kept the display cable hanging in the motherboard, you still have the onboard graphics, and the maximum resolution of the onboard graphics. and that gt 210 won't be used. Try plugging the display cable in the gt 210. If that is already plugged into the graphics card, try plugging it in again.

One of the graphics card connectors are VGA, which also supports resolution up to 1920*1200. If you use a blue connector with screws, try searching for a dvi monitor/cable.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have mentioned it. I use HDMI cable and I plugged it into the port that is in the external graphics card.

Comment: Hmmm... Does your monitor have DVI? the max resolution should only be achivable using dvi (source, webschop)

Comment: No, the monitor is too new for it. How I read what I find on the internet, which is not much, is that the max resolution should be achiavable through digital connections, which I thought HDMI was. Would a dvi>hdmi convertor help?

Comment: if it goes to hdmi2.0, probably yes

Comment: So, if I dug correctly, it is Nvidia GT 210 and it can truly only do 2560*1440 over DVI, however there seem to be no convertors from DVI into either HDMI or DP that would not be limited to FullHD. A pity then :-(.

Comment: Return the gt 210 and buy something newer.

Comment: yea, https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Graphics-Cards/ASUS/GT1030-2G-BRK/ will surely fit in your pcie slot and will work with your hdmi and dp.